# Медленно работает запрос докер на убунте

Tags: ubuntu, docker

На убунте 19.10 использую докер (версия 19.03.6).
Характеристики ноутбука: Memory 15.5 GiB; Intel® Core™ i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8; GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2.
Докер работает очень медленно. У коллеги на маке рестар контейнеров в проекте работает в 3 раза быстрее хотя должно быть наоборот. Выполнение миграции для переноса значений из одной таблицы в другую для 21 тысячи записи заняло 4 часа. У коллеги это заняло 8 минут.
Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону можно "копать"?

Comment: В сторону SSD и оптимизации настроек СУБД? Если тормозит перенос данных по таблицам, то с 99% вероятностью докер тут ни при чём

Comment: @Mike 15.5 GiB же.

Comment: Обвешивайся https://habr.com/ru/post/114082/ и дебаж.